# Css3 transform hover effect is breaking below thumbs in chrome browser

Tags: html, css

Im having 2 days to find solution of this problem which happens only in chrome browser, in other browsers as Safari or Mozzilla everything is working fine

I added my work in [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gazi/u48pgdt5/3/)

If you put your mouse over the last thumb in chrome browser is breaking the below thumbs for one second.

My HTML:

```
<div class="listing-container clearfix">
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="duration">3:59</span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>This is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">798 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating">0%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="duration">3:59</span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>This is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">798 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating">0%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="duration">3:59</span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>This is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">798 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating">0%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="duration">3:59</span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>This is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">798 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating">0%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="duration">3:59</span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>This is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">798 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating">0%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="duration">3:59</span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>This is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">798 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating">0%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="duration">3:59</span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>This is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">798 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating">0%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="duration">15:00</span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>This is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">569 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating">0%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="duration">4:28</span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>This is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">612 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating"> 100%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#kelly-clarkson-breakaway/" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="duration">3:55</span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>This is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">615 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating"> 100%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="ico ico-hd"></span><span class="duration">4:00</span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>This is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">563 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating"> 100%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>IThis is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">499 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating">0%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="video-item " id="bigThumb">
        <div class="outline">
            <a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-thumb">
                <div class="wrapper"><img src="http://shushi168.com/data/out/114/36276270-image.png">
                </div><span class="ico ico-play"></span><span class="duration">15:00</span><span class="site-wrap"><span class="site-info"><i class="btn-play"></i><span class="site-logo"></span></span>
                </span>
            </a><a title="This is a Title" href="#" class="video-item-title"><h2>This is a Title</h2></a>
            <div class="video-item-footer">
                <div class="video-stats clearfix">
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-views">569 Views</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p title="2 years ago" class="stat-when">2 years ago</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="stat">
                        <p class="stat-rating">0%<span class="ico ico-thumbs-up"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.listing-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.listing-container.full-width {
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

.video-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 238px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.full-width .video-item {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.video-item .outline {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.video-item-thumb {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 154px;
  padding: 7px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-item-thumb span.ico,.video-item-thumb span.duration {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: .3s opacity;
  transition: .3s opacity;
}

.video-item-thumb .wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.video-item-thumb:hover span.duration {
  opacity: 0;
}

.video-item-thumb span.ico-play {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  right: 18px;
  bottom: 18px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 38px;
  -moz-border-radius: 38px;
  -ms-border-radius: 38px;
  border-radius: 38px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 38px;
}

.video-item-thumb:hover span.ico-play {
  opacity: 1;
}

.exclusive .video-item-thumb:hover span.ico-play {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

.video-item-thumb span.ico-hd {
  left: 13px;
  bottom: 13px;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 10px 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.video-item-thumb span.duration {
  right: 13px;
  bottom: 13px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -ms-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.video-item-title {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 7px;
  height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.video-item-title h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-item-footer {
  padding: 15px 7px 10px 7px;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 48px;
}

.video-item-footer .video-stats .stat {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
}

.video-item-footer .video-stats .stat:last-child {
  border-right: 0 none;
}

.video-item-footer .video-stats p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-item-footer .video-stats p.stat-views {
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.video-item-footer .video-stats p.stat-when {
  text-align: center;
}

.video-item-footer .video-stats p.stat-rating {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: right;
}

.video-item-footer .video-stats p.stat-rating .ico {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.video-item-thumb,.video-item-thumb:before,.video-item-thumb .wrapper,.video-item-thumb .site-wrap,.video-item .video-item-title {
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.video-item .video-item-title {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.video-item:hover .video-item-thumb .wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.35);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.35);
  transform: scale(1.35);
}

.side-col .video-item:hover .video-item-thumb .wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
  transform: scale(1.4);
}

.video-item.exclusive:hover .video-item-thumb:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ec0819, inset 0 0 0 2px #e71d2c, inset 0 0 0 3px #d31926, inset 0 0 0 4px #cb1724;
}

.video-item.featured.exclusive:hover .video-item-thumb:before {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #ec0819, inset 0 0 0 0 #e71d2c, inset 0 0 0 1px #da1b27, inset 0 0 0 4px #d31926, inset 0 0 0 5px #ce1725, inset 0 0 0 6px #cb1724;
}

.video-item:hover .video-item-thumb {
  height: 194px;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 overflow:hidden;
}
.video-item .video-item-thumb {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  clear: left;
  clear: both;
}
.video-item.featured:hover .video-item-thumb {
  height: 250px;
}
.video-item:hover .video-item-title,.video-item.featured:hover .video-item-title {
  height: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.video-item.exclusive .video-item-thumb:after {
  content: '';
  width: 79px;
  height: 79px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: url("images/label_exclusive.png") 0 0 no-repeat transparent;
}

.video-item.featured .video-item-thumb:after {
  top: 6px;
  left: 6px;
}

.side-col .video-item .video-item-thumb:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.video-item-thumb .site-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.video-item.exclusive:hover .video-item-thumb .site-wrap {
  -moz-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}

.video-item-thumb .site-wrap:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.video-item-thumb .site-wrap .site-info {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 99%;
}

.video-item-thumb .site-info .btn-play {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 36px;
  -moz-border-radius: 36px;
  -ms-border-radius: 36px;
  border-radius: 36px;
}

.video-item-thumb .site-info .btn-play:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -7px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-left: 10px solid #fff;
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
}

.video-item-thumb .site-info .site-logo {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 64px;
  background-image: url("images/pdp_logos.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Do you have any idea what Im doing wrong?
thankyou

Comment: Intuition tells me your hover animation enlarges an element which breaks the flow and makes all elements jump from position, hence the flickering.

Comment: Thanks @Roberrrt but this happens only with last thumb on the right side I tried everything but cant figure it out

Comment: It has something to do with `height: 194px;` (working on it..)

Comment: Yes I tried to change it but nothing happens someone below added an answer but its not any more avaiable

Comment: The newest answer is far better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove float:left on this .video-item and replace with display:inline-block

Comment: Fantastic solution.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gazi/u48pgdt5/8/ I did what you said here but still same problem in chrome browser

Comment: Danstan I see that is working Im just trying to fix my code better yes your code is a solution but it created a big space on the right side and from4 thumbs now I have 3 thumbs inline, however Im going to work with your code and I will check it as a solution

Comment: Im not sure who has updated this one https://jsfiddle.net/u48pgdt5/5/ but seems like a good solution too using .video-item:nth-child(4n+4){ but also this one giving me some problems

Comment: Thanks I have used your one its pushing a bit down but better than before thankyou

Comment: Unfortunately this one now has problems in safari :(